# CloudWatch Alarm for multiple Lambda functions in a CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I am using `SAM` and `CloudFormation` to deploy multiple `Lambda` functions and other resources. The function names are generated by `CloudFormation` and have the following format:

`stack-name-function-name-8H2609XXXXX` with the suffix automatically generated by `CloudFormation`

The `CloudWatch` log groups automatically created for all individual `Lambda` functions have therefore following name format:

`/aws/lambda/stack-name-function-name-8H2609XXXXX`

I am trying to find a way to trigger `CloudWatch Alarm` for the `Lambda` functions in a stack. When creating a `MetricFilter` in `CloudFormation` I have to specify `CloudWatch LogGroupName`. With 100s of `Lambdas` with names generated by `CloudFormation`, following the basic pattern would mean creating 100s of filters that would somehow have to know the names of all functions (outputs and imports maybe but that would be really inflexible when function names change, would require constant redeploying of the "alarm" stack that I was hoping to keep filters in)

Is there a way to maybe trigger alarm for a group of log groups? I imagined using wildcard would be easy on a filter for log group name like `/aws/lambda/stack-name-*`. Or any other nicer approach than having to manage all the filters?

Comment: Just don't let cloudformation generate the names (for anything, really), specify them explicitly, additionally create the loggroup explicitly instead of letting the lambda auto generate it (important anyway e.g. for specifying the log retention) and then add a filter based on the choosen log group name.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was hoping not to have to manually create a log group for every function. Maybe there is a way to aggregate the logs somehow for alerting purpose?

Comment: If multiple resources have the same / similar configuration you should start using modules or nested stacks (or some other IAC tool) such that adding a loggroup is only needed in that module and all 100? usages of that module will all get a log group added.